# How to acces a owner of programmatically created Flyout?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to acces a owner of flyout which i created.

I have code:

```
public void dosomething(Grid lessonGrid)
{
    var invisibleButton = new Button();
    lessonGrid.Children.Add(invisibleButton);

    var contentGrid = new Grid()

    var buttonInFlyOut = new Button { Content="Click" };
    buttonInFlyOut.Click += buttonClicked;

    contentGrid.Children.Add(buttonInFlyOut);

    var flyout = new FlyoutForLessons {
        Content = contentGrid
    };

    flyout.Closed += (f, h) =>
    {
        lessonGrid.Children.Remove(invisibleButton);
    };

    flyout.Owner = lessonGrid;
    flyout.ShowAt(invisibleButton); // i want to acces a owner from parent of invisible Button -> lessonGrid
}

private class FlyoutForLessons : Flyout
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty OwnerOfThisFlyOutProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "owner", typeof(UIElement), typeof(FlyoutForLessons),
        null);

    public UIElement Owner
    {
        get { return (UIElement) GetValue(OwnerOfThisFlyOutProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OwnerOfThisFlyOutProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

This code shows me a flyout. So when i click a button "buttonInFlyOut" i want to get id of "lessonGrid" from sender in this method:

```
   private void buttonClicked_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {

   }
```

As you see, i tried to create a new Flyout with custom property, but i can't get this flyout from sender at method above. I don't know how to do it, and **i don't want to create a private static variable which keeps an instance of grid where flyout's appears.**

If live tree helps:

[image: live tree image of flyout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason why you couldn't handle your click event like this:

```
    public void DoSomething(Grid lessonGrid)
    {
        var invisibleButton = new Button();
        lessonGrid.Children.Add(invisibleButton);

        var contentGrid = new Grid();

        var buttonInFlyOut = new Button { Content = "Click" };
        buttonInFlyOut.Click += (o, args) =>
            {
                this.OnButtonClicked(lessonGrid);
            };

        contentGrid.Children.Add(buttonInFlyOut);

        var flyout = new Flyout { Content = contentGrid };

        flyout.Closed += (f, h) => { lessonGrid.Children.Remove(invisibleButton); };

        flyout.ShowAt(invisibleButton); // i want to acces a owner from parent of invisible Button -> lessonGrid
    }

    private void OnButtonClicked(Grid lessonGrid)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
```

This allows you to access the grid that you passed in to the method.

Due to the way that Flyout isn't a FrameworkElement, you'll never find it in the visual tree which is why you see the pop up in your screenshot is outside of the frame. Without either setting a property that you access in your method or trying it in the way I've described above, I don't think it's possible to do this.

Comment: oh! Thanks, this is what i just needed :D
This problem blocked me to go further

Solution to this problem was so simple :)

Comment: @Niewidzialny that's no problem at all. I'm glad I could help!